# Folium outputs ValueError: missing geometries, however the geojson data looks normal. What am I missing?

Tags: python, twitter, geojson, folium

I'm currently trying to plot a data set of tweets, which I gathered via the Twitter Streaming API and converted to a geojson file, on an interactive map via folium. However, when trying to use the code below, I receive the error message shown below.

Of course I checked my data set, but it seems fine (see below) and it loads without any problem on geojson.io. Am I just having an issue with folium here? Because as far as I can tell, the data (and geometries therein) are fine. Any help will be much appreciated!

Here is a sample of my data:

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [13.4, 52.53]
            },
            "properties": {
                "text": "Busy 2 week ahead! This Saturday spinning all         night in the main room of humboldthain club -#berlin - then     traveling\u2026",
                "created_at": "Mon Apr 15 12:57:26 +0000 2019"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [13.37, 52.50]
            },
            "properties": {
                "text": "OFFICE today.\n.\n.\n#berlin #berlinerphilharmonie #sanofi #eenewolke @ Sanofi Berlin",
                "created_at": "Mon Apr 15 12:59:23 +0000 2019"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

This is the code:

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser
import folium
def get_parser():
    parser = ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--geojson')
    parser.add_argument('--map')
    return parser

def make_map(geojson_file, map_file):
    tweet_map = folium.Map(location=[50, 5],
                           zoom_start=5)
    geojson_layer = folium.GeoJson(open(geojson_file),
                                   name='geojson')
    geojson_layer.add_to(tweet_map)
    tweet_map.save(map_file)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = get_parser()
    args = parser.parse_args()

    make_map(args.geojson, args.map)
```

And this is the error:

```
"Traceback (most recent call last):
File "twitter_map_basic.py", line 21, in <module>
make_map(args.geojson, args.map)
File "twitter_map_basic.py", line 13, in make_map
name = 'geojson'>
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\folium\features.py", line 447, in __init__
raise ValueError<'Cannot render objects with any missing geometries. {!r}'.format(data)
ValueError: Cannot render objects with any missing geometries. <_io.TextIOWrapper name='staedteKlein.geojson' mode='r' encoding='cp1252'>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to load your `geojson_file` before passing it to `folium.GeoJson`:

```
import json
geojson_layer = folium.GeoJson(json.load(open(geojson_file)),
                               name='geojson')
```

or just pass the filename:

```
geojson_layer = folium.GeoJson(geojson_file,
                               name='geojson')
```

The [documentation](https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/modules.html#folium.features.GeoJson) could be more clear that `file` in `data` means file path, not opened file descriptor.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick reply! Works like a charm now :)

Comment: @OsakaJonny Sure, no problem. If the answer resolves your question you can mark it as accepted :) https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers